# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token C in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, json, fetch

Se me esta presentando el siguiente error cuando envió datos para crear un registro: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token C in JSON at position 0, utilizo este código en el JS

```
formulario.addEventListener('submit', function(evento) {
evento.preventDefault();
mostrarAlerta("Datos enviados correctamente");
console.log(datos);

fetch('http://localhost:3000/add', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(datos),
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => console.log(json));
});
```

y asi se tengo definido /add:

```
app.post("/add",(req,res)=>{
let campos = [];
campos.push(req.query.nombres);
campos.push(req.query.apellidos);
campos.push(req.query.correo);
campos.push(req.query.password);
campos.push(req.query.telefono);

let sql = "INSERT INTO `registro_usuarios` (`id`, `nombres`, `apellidos`, `correo`, `password`, `telefono`) VALUES";
sql += `(NULL, '${campos[0]}', '${campos[1]}', '${campos[2]}', '${campos[3]}', '${campos[4]}');`;

conexion.query(sql, (error,results, fields) =>{
    if(error){
        throw error;
    }
    console.log(results,fields);
    res.send("Consulta con exito");
});
```

});

Esto me arroja por consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la linea 32 corresponde a:

```
.then((json) => console.log(json));
```

Cuando reviso la BD desde phpmyadmin el registro se crea pero sin valores todos los campos se llena con undefined, no envia los valores capturados desde el formulario de registro.

Al hacer un console.log del primer .then esta es la respuesta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En el primer `.then()` haz un console.log de `response` para ver su contenido, justo antes de intentar convertir el resultado a json. Muestra el contenido, ahí nos podremos dar cuenta de lo que está ocasionando el problema.

Comment: @ricardo-dlc actualice la pregunta con el console.log, me aparece rejected

Comment: Vale, para el problema del "Unexpected token C in JSON..." creo que el problema es que al retorno de tu función utilizas `res.send()` con un texto plano, cosa que al intentar convertir a JSON te da error puesto que las cadenas planas no son un objeto JSON válido. Si intentas hacer `JSON.parse('Consulta con exito')` obtendrás el mismo error. Para solucionar esto podrías sustituir el `res.send()` por `res.json({msg: "Consilta con exito"})` o en su defecto usar `res.send("\"msg\":\"Consulta con exito\"")` cosa que es más complicado de leer así que yo me iría por la primera opción.

Comment: Para el problema de las inserciones con nulos, una primera sugerencia que te haría es que limites eso a través de la base de datos, agregando el "not null" para evitar problemas como este. Ahora para localizar el problema también sería de mucha ayuda que muestres cómo haces esa petición (a través de la URL quiero decir) y cómo envías los datos que luego ocupas para hacer el query. Si es posible muestra el contenido de `req` y/o de `req.query`.